# add items to a list of a empty list python

Tags: python

Not exactly sure how to ask this question but here it goes.

I have a blank list

I want to add an element to a list within a list.

So in my case I am looking through apache.conf looking for any lines that contain ServerAlias.

If it finds it I want to add that line to the last element of a sub-list.
so....

```
[['ServerAlias test.com']]
```

if it finds another entry in a particuar vhost, it will add that item to the same sub-list.

```
[['ServerAlias test.com','ServerAlias neww.com']]
```

The the next time it goes through new vhost.  I want to add a list to the end of this list and start again.  and so on...

```
[['ServerAlias test.com','ServerAlias neww.com'],['ServerAlias cranberry.com']]
```

I know I did a horrible job describing this.

Here is my non-working code so it may be helpful.

```
def buildvars(fileoutput):
import time
import re
servername=[]
docroot=[]
serveralias=[[]]
vhostdata={}
invhost=0
for line in fileoutput.split('\n'):
    if line == '' or re.search('^#',line) or re.search('^\s+#',line):  #delete blank lines... I dont care about them
        pass
    else: 
        if re.search('^\s*\<VirtualHost', line): #check if we are in a vhost
            invhost=1  #mark that we are in a vhost
            aliascounter=0 
        elif re.search('^\s*\</VirtualHost', line):
            invhost=0
            if aliascounter==0:
                serveralias.append('None') 
        if invhost == 1:
            if re.search('^\s*ServerName.*$',line):  #if we are in a vhost, check if the line contains servername
                servername.append(line.strip())  #then append it to the vhosts list
            if re.search('^\s*DocumentRoot.*$',line):
                docroot.append(line.strip())
            if re.search('^\s*ServerAlias.*$',line):
                if not serveralias: 
                    serveralias[0[0]].append(line.strip())
                else:
                    serveralias[-1[0]].append(line.strip())
                    aliascounter+=1
```

Hope someone knows what i'm talking about.  Merry Christmas!

Comment: In future, please explain what precisely isn't working (e.g. post the exception or unexpected behaviour you're observing) rather than just dumping all your code. In this case it was possible to easily find and fix at least part of your problem because there was a conspicuous error in your code (trying to index a number), but that isn't always the case. Also try to create the simplest code snippet you can that illustrates your problem rather than posting code that contains lots of fluff. If you'd taken some time to create a minimal example here, you'd've probably solved your own problem.

Answer (score 1):

`serveralias[0[0]]` isn't the expression you want. It means 'Take the 0th item of `0`, and then use that as a key to get a value from `serveralias`'. You'll get a `TypeError` whenever Python tries to evaluate that expression because 0 is not indexable.

If you actually wanted to take the 0th item of the 0th item of a list, you'd want to replace that expression with `serveralias[0][0]`. But you don't even want to do that; you just want to append to the 0th item of `serveralias`.

So replace `serveralias[0[0]].append(foo)` with `serveralias[0].append(foo)`, and `serveralias[-1[0]].append(foo)` with `serveralias[-1].append(foo)`.

Not sure if there are any other issues in the code though, I didn't look carefully.

Comment: I did that but am now getting a 'list index out of range'

Comment: @user1601716 My bad. Wasn't paying attention when I answered; located the problem but provided the wrong fix. I've fixed my answer.